# How to implement this image stack effect in Android?

Tags: android

I looked at the H&M Android app and trying to figure out how to implement some widget.
Can anyone have an idea how this image frame is implemented?
I can guess that it using openGL.

[image: https://lh6.ggpht.com/Q-WH9L6rIIPEaEpp2ty0uXH7VqDbVqE_0x2f22o4cjvCHsVm-lTDtfqRkGWRRzywnas]

Comment: do you want to be just a stack effect as above, or you want to stack an image above others (line google 2.3 gallery) ?

Comment: Probably a LinearLayout with an ImageView and a TextView with an image set as the background of the LinearLayout that produces the effect on the border that you're seeing.  For the left-right paging they are probably using a ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

A transparent png frame? Which could also be nine-patch!

Comment: +1 for this approach. Here are some helpful links http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch and http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: This is live effect not an png

Comment: ok then! what about an animated png? It seems too "heavy" to add openGL to just a simple news app! Sure you can implement it but I think its much harder than a sophisticated but simple way!

Answer (score 1):

I will venture a guess ;)

First the front image is created. In this case, it is built by inflating a linear layout with an ImageView and a TextView. Then this is cached to a Bitmap (at setup phase, not draw time).

In onDraw, that bitmap is drawn to the screen. Then the canvas is clipped to avoid drawing that area any more. Saves a lot of drawing time to not do a quadruple overdraw of transparent pixels.

Then the backgrounds are drawn like this:

```
        for(int i = NUMBER_OF_LAYERS - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            canvas.save();
            float rotation = MAX_ANGLE * shiftModifier * ((float) i / (NUMBER_OF_LAYERS - 1));
            canvas.rotate(rotation, mImageHalfWidth, mImageHalfHeight);
            paint.setAlpha((int) (255f / (2 * i)));
            canvas.drawRect(mBitmap.getBounds(), paint);
            canvas.restore();
        }
```

NUMBER_OF_LAYERS is the number of backgrounds layers.

MAX_ANGLE is the rotation angle for the most tilted layer.

shiftModifier is used to animate the background layers. It moves from zero (background completely hidden) to one (background angle = MAX_ANGLE).

paint is just a Paint with color set to white.